# Syntax error in Postgresql but not mySQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm executing this query

```
String innerQueryWithProductVersion = "select test_suite_name, max(m.date) as date "
    +"from  master_table_test_runs m "
    +"INNER JOIN processed_jenkins_runs pdup "
    +"ON m.id=pdup.test_run_id  where m.date < "
    +"(select max(date) from master_table_test_runs "
    +"where product_version =:productVersion) "
    +"and m.test_type!='CLOVER' and m.product = :product "
    +"and m.test_suite_name in "+missingSuites
    +" and m.branch like "+filters.branch
    +" and m.deployment_mode like "+filters.deploymentMode
    +" and pdup.jenkins_server like "+filters.jenkinsInstance
    +" group by m.test_suite_name";


String queryWithProductVersion = "select t.number_tests, "
    +"t.number_failure, t.number_skip, t.number_errors, t.test_type, "
    +"t.product_version, t.date, t.test_suite_name, "
    +"t.branch, p.job_url "
    +"from  master_table_test_runs t INNER JOIN "
    +"(" +innerQueryWithProductVersion+") as x "
    +"INNER JOIN processed_jenkins_runs p ON t.id=p.test_run_id "
    +"where t.test_suite_name = x.test_suite_name "
    +"and t.date = x.date and t.test_suite_name "
    +"in "+missingSuites+" and product = :product "
    +"and p.jenkins_server like "+filters.jenkinsInstance
    +" and t.branch like "+filters.branch
    +" and t.deployment_mode like "+filters.deploymentMode+"";
```

This query its working fine in mysql, but in PostgreSQL its giving syntax errors at "where" and "and"

```
syntax error at or near 'and'
```

Can anyone help me figure out the problem?

Comment: Please show the query *after* string mangling, the final result produced. With all this string concatenation it's hard to say what could be going on. Also, please go and read http://bobby-tables.com/ and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection, fix your code, and try again. I suspect the problem will go away, as it's probably caused by a quote or similar within a string literal.

Comment: Print out the generated statement and run it manually.

Comment: This query its working fyn in mysql, but in PostgreSQL its giving syntax error at "where" and "and".

Comment: Hi there! I rearranged your question so that the query comes before the error. Try to arrange questions so you first explain what your code should do and a brief note about the issue, then show and explain your code followed by the full details of your error such as error code etc. Also make sure that when you add details they're edited into the question itself.

Comment: Which `and` is that exactly? Also: "*syntax error at or near 'and'*"  is not a Postgres error message Usually Postgres also includes the exact position where the error occurs. And a much more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: I think postgresql have no syntax like ```:product```. What ```:``` should do?

Answer (score 0):

one of `"+missingSuites`, `"+filters.branch` etc is not defined, look at sample:

```
t=# select true where 'a' like '' and true;
 bool
------
(0 rows)

t=# select true where 'a' like /*missed value*/ and true;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "and"
LINE 1: select true where 'a' like /*missed value*/ and true;
```